# C++ '==': no conversion from 'int' to 'std::string'

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment, so far I am asking the user whether they want to go first or not. I am wanting to check their input to make sure it matches the two values that I want.

I am getting errors about conversion while using Visual Studio such as:

'==': no conversion from 'int' to 'std::string'

no operator "==" matches these operands

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually read the error message...? `turnChoice == 'yes'` => `turnChoice == "yes"`

Comment: yes, but my point is that I do not know how to deal with the error message

Comment: string write in double "apostrophe". You use 'sigle' legach for character variables, and char is compatible/de facto int

Comment: To explain a bit more, single ' ' are normally used only for single chars and result in their numeric valud (ASCII etc.), eg. 'A' is 65. The compiler is allowed to accept 'yes' too (not a single char) and make transform it into some number (depending on the compiler).

Comment: Okay, I understand now, cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is in the line:

```
if (turnChoice == 'yes' || turnChoice == 'no')
```

C++ and C denote single characters with the single quotation marks, not strings of characters. The compiler is thus attempting to convert your single quotation marks into an integer value. You must use double quotations for string literals. So change the above line to:

```
if (turnChoice == "yes" || turnChoice == "no")
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:    `if (turnChoice == 'yes' || turnChoice == 'no')`
You should use double quotes around strings, like this: `if (turnChoice == "yes" || turnChoice == "no")`.

Answer (score 2):

The remedy is simple: you need to change `'yes'` and `'no'` to `"yes"` and `"no"`, as the latter two are string *literals* with an implicit nul-terminator.

But let's consider why the compiler issues the error that it does.

The single quotations are used to denote a *character literal*. Surprisingly perhaps, an implementation is allowed to permit character literals containing *more* than one `char`:

C11++ standard, §2.14.3/1 - Character literals

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a
>   multicharacter literal . A multicharacter literal has type int and
>   implementation-deﬁned value.

So `'yes'` and `'no'` have type `int`. Since the `std::string` class does not allow assignment to an `int` type it issues the error that you see.

Comment: That's weird! _Surprisingly perhaps_? sure! Why the standard allow this? Just for curiosity, I'd like to know why they went for such a strange feature. I surely prefer a compiler that raise an error for that.

Comment: I will admit to have neither used nor seen this in production code. I can't see a use for it; particularly given that the yielded `int` value is to tightly coupled with your platform's character encoding (ASCII, EBCDIC, etc) and the nuances of the `int` type used by your platform.